# Nifi Create Controller Service Through Rest-API

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to create a DbcpController service from nifi rest api. I am getting the proper response also but when i go to UI, The controller service is not visible.

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/json' 
-d '{"revision":{"clientId":"a09f2359-0165-1000-bf28-1dca98f6e259","version":0},
"permissions":{"canRead":true,"canWrite":true},"bulletins":[],
"component":{"name":"Dynamic-Pool","type":"org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool",
"bundle":{"group":"org.apache.nifi","artifact":"nifi-dbcp-service-nar","version":"1.6.0"},
"controllerServiceApis":[{"type":"org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPService",
"bundle":{"group":"org.apache.nifi","artifact":"nifi-standard-services-api-nar","version":"1.6.0"}}],
"comments":"","state":"DISABLED","persistsState":false,"restricted":false,"deprecated":false,
"multipleVersionsAvailable":true,"properties":{"Database Connection URL":"jdbc:oracle:thin:@144.21.86.182:1521/ORCL.607022672.oraclecloud.internal",
"Database Driver Class Name":"oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
"database-driver-locations":"/home/siddharth/Downloads/ojdbc7.jar","Database User":"test","Password":"***",
"Max Wait Time":"500 millis","Max Total Connections":"8","Validation-query":null},"descriptors":{ } } }' 
http://localhost:9090/nifi-api/controller/controller-services/
```

Response :

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Mon, 03 Sep 2018 18:19:28 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Location: http://localhost:9090/nifi-api/controller-services/a0a93568-0165-1000-0c3b-ff9494571881
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: User-Agent
Content-Length: 3614
Server: Jetty(9.4.3.v20170317)
```

If i click the location the details also comes up.

Is there any parameter in the request which i am missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what "When I go to UI, the controller service is not visible" means.

1. When you go to the Apache NiFi UI, and click **[Global Menu](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#User_Interface) > Controller Settings > Controller Services**, you do not see any Controller Services listed -- *Possibly refresh your browser and clear the cache? I don't think this is your issue*
2. The Controller Service is listed but it is not available to use in a processor -- *this is because the CS is being added to the global level, which means it is available for Reporting Tasks to reference, but not processors on the canvas. You'll need to provide a `parentGroupId` in the `ControllerServiceDTO` object in the JSON in order for the CS to be available to a component on the canvas (in that parent group). Your URL will look like this: `/nifi-api/process-groups/a0f3dfb7-0165-1000-8310-4fb72628adaa/controller-services`. **I think this is your issue***
3. The Controller Service is available to use in a processor but it is not enabled -- *this is because you are setting the state of the CS to `DISABLED`. You can issue an additional command which enables the CS, or set the state to `ENABLED` initially*

If you right click on the canvas and select **Configure**, you'll get a dialog for the Process Group you're in (called "NiFi Flow" by default at the *root* level), and there is a tab for "Controller Services", which will list the CS you have created.

[image: The process group configuration dialog on the Controller Services tab]

You can always perform these operations in the UI and use your browser's Developer Tools panel to monitor the requests -- NiFi's UI is a consumer of the REST API, so any activity performed there can be done using the API alone.

Examples:

**Add a reporting task controller service**

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/controller/controller-services' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:8080' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:8080/nifi/' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'DNT: 1' --data-binary '{"revision":{"clientId":"a0f490b8-0165-1000-a521-4d24892f12c0","version":0},"disconnectedNodeAcknowledged":false,"component":{"type":"org.apache.nifi.processors.aws.credentials.provider.service.AWSCredentialsProviderControllerService","bundle":{"group":"org.apache.nifi","artifact":"nifi-aws-nar","version":"1.8.0-SNAPSHOT"}}}' --compressed
```

**Enable a reporting task controller service**

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/controller-services/a0f4dbe2-0165-1000-8cd2-dd50d7dba48d' -X PUT -H 'Origin: http://localhost:8080' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:8080/nifi/' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'DNT: 1' --data-binary '{"revision":{"clientId":"a0f490b8-0165-1000-a521-4d24892f12c0","version":1},"disconnectedNodeAcknowledged":false,"component":{"id":"a0f4dbe2-0165-1000-8cd2-dd50d7dba48d","state":"ENABLED"}}' --compressed
```

**Add a controller service available to a component on the canvas**

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/process-groups/a0f3dfb7-0165-1000-8310-4fb72628adaa/controller-services' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:8080' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:8080/nifi/?processGroupId=root&componentIds=a0f7e36a-0165-1000-ef42-c59f18644d42' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'DNT: 1' --data-binary '{"revision":{"clientId":"a0f490b8-0165-1000-a521-4d24892f12c0","version":0},"disconnectedNodeAcknowledged":false,"component":{"type":"org.apache.nifi.ssl.StandardRestrictedSSLContextService","bundle":{"group":"org.apache.nifi","artifact":"nifi-ssl-context-service-nar","version":"1.8.0-SNAPSHOT"},"name":"StandardRestrictedSSLContextService"}}' --compressed
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks @Andy I was missing the processorGroup. I am able to see it now.